# How to check and cast generic parameters in Dart?

Tags: dart, generics

I am implementing some dynamic input validator in Dart. See code:

```
abstract class Validator<T> {
  void validate(T value);
  
  static Validator<T> create<T>(String validatorType) {
    if (validatorType == 'name') {
      return NameValidator<T>();
    }
    if (validatorType == 'range') {
      // How to write:  assert(T is Comparable)
      return RangeValidator<T>(); //  error: 'T' doesn't extend 'Comparable<dynamic>'.
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class NameValidator<T> extends Validator<T> {
  @override
  void validate(T value) {
    assert(value.toString() == "foo");
  }
}

class RangeValidator<T extends Comparable> extends Validator<T> {
  @override
  void validate(T value) {
    assert(value.compareTo(42) < 0);
  }
}
```

The static function of the base class `Validator.create()` will create an instance of subclass based on the given `validatorType`. The generic paramater `T` in subclass `RangeValidator` class needs to be comparable, but it is not a requirement in base class `Validator` and subclass `NameValidator`.

I have two questions:

1. How to write code the validate the generic type `T` extends `Comparable`?
2. How to cast type `T` to `Comparable` to instantiate the subclass `RangeValidator`?

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible since this would not be possible to analyze when compiling. Generics must be able to be determined by the analyzer but since `create`'s behavior is controlled by an argument, which can be set at runtime, the analyzer cannot predict the type of the returned value or predict what type would be valid as `T`. Instead of the `validatorType` argument, you should create multiple methods like `createNameValidator<T>` where you can then define the type requirement for `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

You can check whether `T` is a subtype of `Comparable` in a number of ways. The easiest is probably a helper function like:

```dart
bool isSubtype<Sub, Super>() => <Sub>[] is List<Super>;
```

That won't help you with the other half of the problem, though.

There is no way in Dart to "promote" a type variable to have a bound that it didn't originally have. The language can promote a *value* of type `T` to have a magical intersection type `T & Comparable`, say by doing `T x = ...; if (x is Comparable) { ... x is "T&Comparable" here ...}`, but it can't use that for anything expect calling `Comparable` members on the value.
It doesn't affect the type `T` (because `T` might not be a subtype of `Comparable` just because the value is).

And there is no promoting type variables.

So, you can do 1, but you cannot do 2.

Comment: Thanks. For question 2, I end up with casting the value of type T to Comparable. Something like `assert((value1 as Comparable).compareTo(value2))`.